# Forwarding traffic from vpn to eth on specific port

Tags: iptables

On my raspberry I have two interfaces eth0 connected to the router and tun0 iface (openvpn).

Usually I connect to house raspy between openvpn. Inside my network I have a camera on 192.168.1.12.

When I'm connect from outside with vpn I want to:

- connect to **openvp-ip**:8888  -> **ipcamera**:80 (to access admin panel camera)
- forward rtsp (554) from **openvpn-ip**:554 -> **ipcamera**:554

How can do this with iptables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need two rules for port forwarding:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d <openvpn-ip> -p tcp --dport 8888 -j DNAT --to-destination <camera-ip>:80
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d <openvpn-ip> -p tcp --dport 554 -j DNAT --to-destination <camera-ip>:554
```

Also you need allow the forwarded packets:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -j ACCEPT
```